# Bundling local gem (that I'm developing) does not seem to include lib directory (using rvm)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm trying to develop a gem locally, and have installed it with Bundler.

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gemspec
```

And my gemspec is a standard gemspec file.

I can install the gem with 'bundle install' in the directory, and i see the local gem and all it's dependencies install:

```
bundle install
Using rack (1.3.4) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sinatra (1.3.1)  
Using {my gem} (0.0.2) from source at . 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

However, when I do a 'gem list', my gem is not included in the list of gems - which is my guess as to why my bin directory does not appear in the path. Is there a way to test a local gem and include it in the list of installed gems using bundler, so that the bin directory properly works?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get rid of `bundler: command not found: {your bin executable}`:

```
git add bin/*  # git-ls-files will now list your bin executables.
bundle install 
# No git-commit necessary.
bundle exec <MY_BIN_EXECUTABLE>
```

Comment: bah, I forgot that bundler's generated gemspec uses git-ls-files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`gem list` shows your system installed gems, not the gems in your Bundle (this are often the same but not always--as in this case). When you're using Bundler, you should always execute gem executables with `bundle exec` so that Bundler can set up the environment for you. So, if you have a binary called, for example, `mygem`, you should use `bundle exec mygem`.

See more info at [Bundler's site](http://gembundler.com/) or in the [manpage](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html).

[Edit]

Also be sure that your gemspec includes a [bin directory](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#bindir)! Common convention is to create a directory called `bin` at the same level as your `lib` directory, put your binaries in there, and then add this as the directory in your gemspec. If you don't do this, Bundler won't expose your binaries!

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I do have a binary in the bin directory, with the same name as the gem (so, {gemname}/bin/{gemname}. I tried bundle exec mygem, but got the message: `bundler: command not found: mygem
Install missing gem executables with bundle install`. I ran the command from within the {gemname} directory

Comment: Did you actually run `bundle exec mygem` or `bundle exec name_of_binary`? Also, do you also have the `bindir` line in your .gemspec? Although the spec says it defaults to `bin`, it may be worth including it.

Comment: I actually tried both, still no luck. I thought that perhaps bundler was having trouble with bin file being named same as gem, but changing that didnt help either. I have this in my gemspec (came default from bundler): `  s.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }`. Any other ideas? Your assistance did work elsewhere, however - I worked out another issue I was having because I wasn't using `bundle exec` - so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

Make sure the executables and default_executable lines don't contain 'bin/'. Then:

```
git add add . # You can be more precice if you want.
git commit -m "My lousy commit message."
bundle install
bundle exec <binaryname>
```